# Internal Server error after push my node js application on IBM cloud

Tags: node.js, express, devexpress, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

[enter image description here][1]We developed node js app on local pc

the am trying to push the app (following the tutorial provide by IBM )  but after pushing successfully when i try to open the application (appname.mybluemix.com)  i got "Internal Server Error"

Although the url take automatically the route of the login page of our application

The node js service is linked to availability monitoring service, mongo DB and IOT platform

Am sure am using the correct pushing commands because we already pushed another app from github and it works fine

Kindly  check part of the CF log for our app

Thanks in advance

> 2019-01-19T08:31:06.48+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at Layer.handle
>   [as handle_request]
>   (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>   2019-01-19T08:31:06.48+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at trim_prefix
>   (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>   2019-01-19T08:31:06.48+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
>   /home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>   2019-01-19T08:31:06.48+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
>   Function.process_params
>   (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>   2019-01-19T08:31:06.48+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at next
>   (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>   2019-01-19T08:46:06.44+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Error: Failed to
>   lookup view "login.ejs" in views directory "/home/vcap/app/views"
>   2019-01-19T08:46:06.44+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at
>   EventEmitter.render
>   (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)

Comment: Is it supposed to be looking for a login.ejs instead of login.js? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is most likely to be a problem with how you have constructed your express application, or copied it, and the default settings.

Express in looking for the embedded javascript template `index.ejs` that it thinks defines your `index` page. As it isn't found I guess you don't have it in `/home/vcap/app/views`

It will be looking for a `ejs` file either because you have explicitly said it should in your routes, or it is looking for a `.ejs` module because the default template engine has been set as `ejs` for the application.

Somewhere in your application, most likely `app.js`, you will have a line like

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Either modify this line to use the template engine that your `index` file does provide, or create an `index.ejs` file.